# Symfony - Composer and Payone PHP SDK

Tags: symfony, composer-php, payone

I'm trying to use the PHP-SDK and I just can't get it to work. I'm not familiar with the use and namespace statements in PHP and I'm trying to understand it.

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "payone/php-sdk",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://github.com/PAYONE/PHP-SDK/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-0": { "Payone_": "php/" }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "payone/php-sdk": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

As far as I understand this tries to load the Autoload.php in my payone/php-sdk/php folder with the class prefix Payone_. This seems fine to me but I can't use `$builder = new Payone_Builder();` in my controller now. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the use statement to your controller.

```
use Payone_Builder;
```

Comment: no need for the use statement if you just do `new \PayOne_Builder();`

Answer (score 0):

as per 2015/03 new zip url

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "payone/php-sdk",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://www.payone.de/uploads/media/php-sdk.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "psr-0": {"Payone_": "php/"}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```